# Elasticsearch: Getting hash from the whole search result

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there anyway to create a hash from the results of a query, so that we can detect the change later(by comparing new and old hash)?

Currently The only solution would be performing scan/scroll curious that there may be simpler solutions?